# angular directive : dynamic inject controller change the origin controller

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, controller, directive

I write a directive which I need dynamic inject the controller by name, such code like below:

but I find the real controller which has been inject outside change to the child controller of the  origin controller.

### So how to inject the controller by name and not change the origin controller outside?

```
angular.module('bsTable', []).directive('bsTable', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                bsTable: '='
            },
            replace: true,
            controller: "@",
            name: "controllerName",
            link: function (scope, el, attr, ctl) {
                scope.instantiated = false;
                scope.$watch('bsTable.options', function (value) {
                    if (!value) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (scope.instantiated) {
                        $(el).bootstrapTable('destroy');
                    }
                    $(el).bootstrapTable(angular.copy(value));
                    $(el).bind('post-body.bs.table', function () {
                        var body = el.find('tbody')[0];
                        $compile(body)(scope);
                        $(window).resize(function () {
                            $(el).bootstrapTable('resetView');
                        });
                    });
                    scope.instantiated = true;
                }, true);

                scope.$on('table-refresh', function () {
                    $(el).bootstrapTable('refresh');
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

the whole code is above.
And the usage of this directive is like below:

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
    <table bs-table="bsTable" controller-name="searchDiscountController"></table>
</div>
```

before use the directive, the id of instance of searchDiscountController  is 3, and the html model under searchDiscountController can bind correctly.

after use the directive, I find the id of the origin searchDiscountController instance change to 4, and the id of scope in directive is 4 too.

But the html model under searchDiscountController is working in a controller instance which id is 3.

So when I get the value of the ng-model, I need to visit the **$parent** to get the value...

I'm so puzzled...

Comment: There must be a good reason for this. Can you share the scenario in more detail.

Comment: If you need to call some action on another controller, use $on and $broadcast. (look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

Comment: update my question..Thanks